# Con MongoDB que puedo hacer

Tags: javascript, sql, web, mongodb

Buen día 
Estoy aprendiendo javascript y nodejs pero no estoy seguro si debería aprender MongoDB, quiero hacer una página web, que funcione  como un cajero, compra y venta de productos alimenticios, incluso si se fía algún producto, nosé si mongodb pueda hacer tantas relaciones, si no es una base de datos para eso cual me recomendarían? Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], las preguntas bAsadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: Perdón, no era mi intención.